# Downloading torrent files Using Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have some simple Questions.

What is the flow of Torrent to Google Drive using Colab ?
Why it is faster than regular Torrent Clint like uTorrent?
Is it possible to change the code to download locally ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just speculation, assuming that you compare `regular torrent client` (uTorrent running on your local computer with your network connection, i.e. cellular network/dial up/cooper LAN) and `google colab torrent client` (torrent client running in google colab environment, either through python torrent client or through `!apt install ....`). Then the speed of torrent download/upload would be determined by network speed (e.g. bandwidth, ping, geographic location). It's very likely that Google's network is faster than your computer's network, hence the faster speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this to run QBittorrent in Colab. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8WYjHfdcoX5GAnRhDQnhqe_H8MEfM1i?usp=sharing

I don't think you can make it download locally.